# AFNetworking.h file not found when building for tests?

Tags: ios, xcode5, afnetworking, afnetworking-2, kiwi

I am working on an iOS project which was using `AFNetworking v1.3.1` without an issue. Recently, we decided not to support `iOS 5.0` any more and updated the project to support `iOS 6.0` and also pod versions accordingly. I have migrated the project to `AFNetworking v2.3.1` and it works like a charm when running the project both on device and simulator. Yet it fails when trying to run Kiwi tests. It gives the error:

```
'AFNetworking.h' file not found
```

Do not get me wrong, I have searched SO and AFNetworking's issues page but all I can find is changing the `Header Search Paths` would fix similar issues yet not mine. Xcode cannot even find anything related to AFNetworking when test build.

This is my pod file:

```
platform :ios, '6.0'
pod 'Kiwi/XCTest', '2.2.4'
pod 'AFNetworking', '2.3.1'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.8'
pod 'FMDB'
pod 'JSONModel'
```

This is Header Search Paths for product target and tests target respectively:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/AFNetworking"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/FMDB"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/JSONModel"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Kiwi"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/MBProgressHUD"
```

#

```
$(inherited)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/AFNetworking"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/FMDB"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/JSONModel"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Kiwi"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/MBProgressHUD"
```

I might be looking at the wrong direction, so if you could point me to right one it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the Kiwi test target have the new AFNetworking as a dependency?

Comment: It was not. I have added it yet no luck. I cannot understand that people say that AFNetworking.h is not included in 2.x yet I have this header file and it works on production environment, just not on test environment.

Comment: Just inserted `link_with` to my pod file as suggested in an SO answer but it did not seem to change anything.

Comment: @sercancici did you figure this out??

Comment: Yes I've sorted it out and I still do not have any idea why. The `import` statement was in .h file (I do not remember which class) when I moved it to .m it just magically started working. Hope it helps.